# How to increase network efficiency on a Google Cloud VM

Tags: python, mysql, google-bigquery

I'm currently building an ETL on a Google Cloud based VM (Windows Server 2019 - 4 vCPUs) to execute the following process:

1. Extract some tables from a MySQL replica db
2. Adjust data types for Google BigQuery conformities
3. Upload the data to BigQuery using Python's **pandas_gbq** library

To illustrate, here are some parts of the actual code (Python, iterator over one table):

```py
while True:

    # GENERATES AN MYSQL QUERY BASED ON THE COLUMNS AND THEIR
    # RESPECTIVE TYPES, USING A DICTIONARY TO CONVERT
    # MYSQL D_TYPES TO PYTHON D_TYPES

    sql_query = gen_query(cols_dict=col_types, table=table,
                          pr_key=p_key, offset=offset)

    cursor = cnx.cursor(buffered=True)
    cursor.execute(sql_query)

    if cursor.rowcount == 0:
        break

    num_fields = len(cursor.description)
    field_names = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]

    records = cursor.fetchall()

    df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=columns)
    offset += len(df.index)

    print('Ok, df structured')

    # CHECK FOR DATETIME COLUMNS

    col_parse_date = []

    for column in columns:
        if col_types[column] == 'datetime64':
            try:
                df[column] = df[column].astype(col_types[column])
                col_parse_date.append(column)

            except:
                df[column] = df[column].astype(str)
                for i in to_bgq:
                    if i['name'] == column:
                        i['type'] = 'STRING'

    # UPLOAD DATAFRAME TO GOOGLE BIGQUERY

    df.to_csv('carga_etl.csv', float_format='%.2f',
              index=False, sep='|')
    print('Ok, csv recorded')
    df = ''
    df = pd.read_csv('carga_etl.csv', sep='|')
    print('Ok, csv read')

    df.to_gbq(destination_table='tr.{}'.format(table),
              project_id='iugu-bi', if_exists='append', table_schema=to_bgq)
```

The logic is based on a query generator; it gets the MySQL table Schema and adjusts it to BigQuery formats (e.g. Blob to STRING, int(n) to INTEGER etc.), querying the full results (paginated with an offset, 500K rows per page) and saving it in a dataframe to then upload it to my new database.

Well, the ETL does its job, and I'm currently migrating my tables to the cloud. However, I'm worried I'm subutilizing my resources, due to network traffic gaps. Here is the network report (bytes/sec) from my VM reporting section:

[VM Network Bytes report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUMjB.png)

According to that report, my in/out network data peaks at 2/3 MBs, which is really low compared to the average 1GBs available if I use the machine to download something from my browser, for example.

My point is, what am I doing wrong here? Is there any way to increase my MySQL query/fetch speed and my upload speed to BigQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are transforming datetime64 to a compatible [BigQuery Data type](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/BigQuery-Data-Type-Conversions_102563896), correct me if I am wrong.

I have a few recommendations:

1. You can use [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs) as it is a ETL product and it is optimized for performance
2. Depending on your overall use case and if you are using [CloudSQL/MySQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql), you can use [BigQuery Federated queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries).
3. Again depending on your use case, you caould use a MySQL dump and upload the data in GCS or directly to BigQuery.